# Bitcoin Mining on Office Network

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, linux, server, windows

I'm a bitcoin novice and i've read a bit about mining. It got me thinking that I could setup our office network to min bitcoin (obviously with permission)

We have a centos linux server which is on 24/7/365 and we have 6 windows 7 machines which are on 8 hours a day during a working week when staff are in working.

Is it possible to setup the linux server to mine bitcoins continuously with very low effect to the server's load and the same with all the windows 7 machines? What sort of mining software would be idea for the setup.

Comment: Basically your wasting your time, look at a bitcoin mining calculator and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

CPU and GPU mining costs more in electricity than it rewards in BTC at the moment.
You need special equipment with ASIC chips to mine at a profit.
These chips are designed to perform many hashes at low power consumption.

I suggest you ask your boss if he agrees with the negative efficiency of your current setup.

Comment: +1 for asking the boss (regardless of overall efficiency). I think there had been several news items when CPU mining was stiff profitable claiming that employees got fired just for doing this without asking their bosses first.

Comment: Always ask first. If I remember correctly there was a case in France where someone used their machine at work to mine without permission and ended up having to give the profits to the company.

Comment: I run the IT network for the company and will be discussing the possibility with the director of using the employee's computers  and the server which is on anyway for mining while they are on. I just need to know if it will be worth doing. After all, the PCs are on at the time anyway.

Comment: It stopped being profitable almost a year ago. Even if your computers already are running 24/7, mining will cause them to use more power, I doubt that the return would balance the increased power bill.